# Dynamic calculations tied to dynamic fields

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net

I have an ASP.NET website. I have a page where the controls are dynamically created/placed. In the database, there's a table called TableControls. For example... (first row is column name)

```
ID  ControlName      ControlType  XPos   YPos    Formula     
1   SalesValue1      Textbox      110    200     
2   SalesValue2      Textbox      110    300
3   SalesValueTotal  Textbox      110    400     =[SalesValue1]+[SalesValue2]
```

As you can see, the Formula field is "calculated", much like in Excel. Currently I've coded the dynamic placements of controls with no problem.

What I would like is for the dynamically placed SalesValueTotal textbox to display the result based on the formula field. Any suggestions on how to do this? I prefer it to handle like Excel, so that when SalesValue1 or SalesValue2 is changed then SalesValueTotal is updated automatically. The tricky part is that all controls are created dynamically. So, any javascript would need to be created dynamically as well.

I'm thinking that I need to dynamically append javascript to all textbox controls to call a calculation function. The calculation function would dynamically be created in code-behind (VB.NET) and would run all calculations on the page then inserted into the page.

Am I over-complicating this? Any suggestion? Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using  any `MVVM` JS Library like `Knockout.js` ? http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html

Comment: I have not. But I need a quick implementation so I might run out of time. But I will take a look.